# Passing a jQuery event as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can do this with JavaScript:

```
function bar(test) {
    alert(test);
}
var foo = bar;
foo('hi');
```

I'd like to be able to do something similar with a jQuery event:

```
var foo = $('#bork').click;
foo(function() { alert('I was just clicked.'); });
```

However, I get an error when the page loads: `this.bind is not a function`. Am I doing something wrong with the events here? Is there a better way to get the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#bork').bind('click', foo);
function foo() { alert('i was just clicked'); }
```

Comment: I knew it had something to do with bind(). Thanks.

Comment: There is no difference in functionality at all between $("#bork").click(...) and $("#bork").bind("click", ...). Refer to Kip's reply to see the real issue here.

Comment: You and Kip both misunderstood his question. Kip's remarks are no doubt interesting but they're not addressing what he is trying to do, which my answer does.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers don't seem to be addressing the technical question:

Why does this work:

```
$('#bork').click(function() { alert('I was just clicked.'); });
```

But not this:

```
var foo = $('#bork').click;
foo(function() { alert('I was just clicked.'); });
```

The two appear to be the same, but the problem is that "`this`" within the implementation of the `click` function refers to the jQuery object in the first example, but it refers to `foo` in the second example.  Since you have not defined `foo.bind`, the call to "`this.bind`" in the implementation of `click` fails.

Here is [a great article about the ins and outs of binding/scoping in Javascript](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`bind`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind#typedatafn) function.

```
$('#bork').bind("click", function() { 
    alert('I was just clicked.'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$("#bork").bind("click", function() { alert("I was just clicked"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define foo as a function to make your sample work. If you change the definition of foo a little it will work:

```
var foo = function(f) {$('#bork').click(f);};
foo(function() { alert('I was just clicked.'); });
```